# Update one data.table with multiple-column key if the keys in another data.table match

Tags: r, key, data.table

I'm having issues understanding how to approach data.tables that are keyed. What I would like, is to update a data.table if the values are matching in another data.table, otherwise leave as is.

Here's a MRE:

```
a <- data.table(country = c("AD", "AD", "DE"), post =c("AD500", "AD500", "60381"), city = c("andora", 'Andorra la Vella', "Frankfurt" ))
setkeyv(a,c("country","post"))

b <- data.table(is = c("AD", "DE", "MX"), code = c("AD500", "60381", "45030"), "locality" = c("Andorra la Vella", "Frankfurt am Main", "Zapopan"))
setkeyv(b,c('is','code'))
```

Things that have not worked:

```
a[b, `:=` (city = i.locality ), on = .(country, post)]
#Error in `[.data.table`(a, b, `:=`(city = i.locality), on = .(country,  : 
#Column(s) [country,post] not found in i
a[b, `:=` (city = i.locality ), on = .(is, code)]
#Error in `[.data.table`(a, b, `:=`(city = i.locality), on = .(is, code)) : 
#Column(s) [is,code] not found in x
```

Expected result:

```
   country  post              city
1:      AD AD500  Andorra la Vella
2:      AD AD500  Andorra la Vella
3:      DE 60381 Frankfurt am Main
```

Row `1` and `3` were updated as they are also found in `b` with a different value.

Comment: DId you meant `a[b, ':=' (city = i.locality) , on = .(country = is, post = code)]`  I guess the `on` argument still expects the same column name or specify the name is equal to the new name

Comment: In addition to what akrun said, since a is keyed and the first two columns of b are what you want to merge on `a[b, city := i.locality ]` happens to work.

Comment: @akrun that did it, thanks